# Mixing Python and Bash in iPython

Tags: bash, ipython

I understand `!` tells iPython to treat the expression as "Bashy", but how do I tell iPython to treat an expression as "Pythony" so I can mix the two together?

For example, if I have a list of folders, how do I `cd` into them by indexing into the list?

```
In [57]: x = !find . -type d

In [58]: !cd x[-1]
sh: line 0: cd: x[-1]: No such file or directory
```

iPython is not making the substitution for `x[-1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
!cd {x[-1]}
```

If you want change current dir of ipython:

```
cd {x[-1]}
```

Comment: What's the functional difference between the first one and second one?

Comment: The first one forks a new process, so it won't change the ipython(it's parent)'s current dir.